# SQL Select: multiple customers have muliple order lines. list each customer and true false whether certain lines ordered

Tags: sql-server-2005, select

I have a SQL Server 2005 table which lists customers and their order lines like this...

```
Cust  | Code 
Cust1   N001
Cust2   N001
Cust2   N003
Cust2   N004
Cust3   N001
Cust3   N002
Cust3   N003
Cust3   N004
```

I need the results to list each customer (Once) and whether they have ordered ANY items between N002 and N004. The results would therefore look like this...

```
Cust  | Ordered?
Cust1   False
Cust2   True
Cust3   True
```

I have tried various combinations of All / ANY etc. The closest I got was using two queries. In the first I would add the following to get a true/false statement to the end of each line ...

```
SELECT 
    Cust, Code, 
    CASE 
        WHEN Code BETWEEN 'N002' AND 'N004' THEN 'True' 
        ELSE 'False' 
    END AS Expr1
```

This gives the following...

```
Cust  | Code | EXPR1
Cust1   N001   FALSE
Cust2   N001   FALSE
Cust2   N003   TRUE
Cust2   N004   TRUE
Cust3   N001   FALSE
Cust3   N002   TRUE
Cust3   N003   TRUE
Cust3   N004   TRUE
```

Then using a second query and grouping the results I get

```
Cust  | Ordered?
Cust1   False
Cust2   False
Cust2   True
Cust3   False
Cust3   True
```

So could any one help to achieve simply...

```
Cust  | Ordered?
Cust1   False
Cust2   True
Cust3   True
```

Comment: Are "cust" and "code" in the same table, or are you using a join?

Comment: Sorry, the table is actually a view. The view made from a statement concerning several tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to add a variable specifying whether the value is in range, and then checking that in the case statement:

```
SELECT Cust,
       (case when sum(inrange) > 0 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END) AS count
from (select t.*,
             (case when code between 'N002' and 'N004' then 1 else 0 end) as inrange
      from t
     ) t
group by cust
```

You can actually combine the two case statements into one, if you don't care about the readability of your code.

Comment: This will work, but isn't necessarily an optimal solution.  Among other things, you're doing an aggregate, when you're really attempting to check for existence (this may sum way too many rows).  Also, (although the OP didn't specify), this will only return customers that have placed orders, not _all_ customers.

Comment: Could you explain further?  It is rather hard to see how to avoid an aggregate, since the original table has multiple rows per customer and the output has only one row.

Comment: OK, not sure what an aggregate is. Yes I wanted to list all customers whether they had ordered or not and I can see I did not highlight this in my OP. I wanted to list all customers and whether they had ordered from a particualr range of products

Comment: The table (Which is actually a view - Sorry) is a list of customers and their orderlines over the past 6 months (So there are 16k lines in the real view)

Comment: Aggregation is what "group by" does.  My point is simply that the solution with a join and distinct *is* doing an aggregation (as well as a join), you just don't see it explicitly in the query.  Without indexes, my solution should require less work.  With indexes, you have the big "it depends".

Comment: Well this solution works perfectly so thank you very much indeed !!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have some sort of customer table.  If so, this is trivially doable with the following:

```
SELECT Customer.id, 
CASE WHEN DidOrder.customerId IS NOT NULL THEN true ELSE false END as ordered
FROM Customer
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT customerId
           FROM OrderLine
           WHERE code >= 'N002' 
           AND code < 'N005') DidOrder
ON DidOrder.customerId = Customer.id
```

This will check for all customers, regardless of whether or not they have an order.

Comment: Yep, this is the way I'd do it, although true and false may need to go into text qualifiers depending on the DBMS.